# Can we add new functionality of generic class from client side?

Tags: c#, .net, class, generics

Suppose I have a generic class of Product.

```
public class Product
{
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }
    public int UnitsInStock { get; set; }
}
```

In client side code would be

```
 List<Product> prdList = new List<Product>();
```

**My Question, is it possible to add a new functionality of Generic List collection from client side without affecting the actual Generic Product Class?**

Comment: You might be like to look at "Decorator" design pattern. It helps you adding new functionality w/o modifying original class.

Comment: What kind of functionality do you mean?

Comment: If I want to add ProductSKU at Client code.

Comment: Your `Product` class is not even generic, what do you mean by `client code` ?

Comment: Product class is Library. Client code is nothing but where the user using this product class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just subclass `Product`:

```
public class OurProduct : Product
{
    public string ProductSKU { get; set; }
}
```

and use it as such:

```
List<OurProduct> prdList = new List<OurProduct>();
```